# Scanner class input issues

Tags: java, input

Hi I am trying to solve large input of fair and square of google code jam of this year. I have got a good enough fast working code for large problem 1.
However when I paste input it in console does not read all of it. Infact it just reads the last input for some reason. I want to paste input and get output. Is the scanner class causing the problem?

Code :

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class rishab {
 public static int check() {
 Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
 double A=reader.nextLong();
 long B=reader.nextLong();
 int count = 0;
 long i;
 if((long)Math.sqrt(A)==Math.sqrt(A))
   i= (long)Math.sqrt(A);
 else
  i=(long)Math.sqrt(A)+1; 
for(;i<=Math.sqrt(B);i++) {
 if(i==reverse(i) && Math.pow(i,2)==reverse((long)Math.pow(i,2)))
  count++;
 }
 return(count);
 }

 public static long reverse(long number) {
  long result = 0;
  while (number != 0) {
   long remainder = number % 10;

    result = result * 10 + remainder;

    number /= 10;
 }
 return result;
 }
  public static void main(String str[]) {
 int[] a= new int[10000];

 Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
 int T= reader.nextInt();

for(int i=0;i<T;i++)
 a[i]=check();
for(int i=0;i<T;i++)
 System.out.println("Case #"+(i+1)+": "+a[i]);
}
}
```

Now the problem is if I for example PASTE input :

```
5
1 100
2 200
1 500
1 1000000
1 1000000000
```

It wont work
but if i type each line separately it will work
What do i do so that I can paste the input?
Thanks

Comment: tell me what's ur question .... and waht do you want as output

Comment: Question - http://code.google.com/codejam/contest/2270488/dashboard#s=p2
I am quite sure I solved it correctly. I just dont know how to paste the input for the scanner class to read it.

Comment: you mean if you enter limit 5 , then your program must real 5 lines right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
String input ="";
while (reader.hasNextLine()){
    input =  reader.nextLine();
    //parse each line   

}
```